# How to make a cartoon like trail particle system?

Tags: unity, graphics, graphic-effects

I'm currently working on an little Android game, it's a reaction casual game. Because the user needs to tap some balls flying around at the right moment, I want to add some new effects to them.

So I looked at some other games and found this cool looking cartoon like effect.

[image: Picture]
As you can see the ball there has an cool tail.

So my question is, does anyone know how to recreate such a trail with the Unity particle effects or some other tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this with the [TrailRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html) component. When you want your game object to have more than one trail, you might have to add some sub-objects to it with their own trail renderers.

Comment: Unity isn't tagged?

Comment: @Sidar The last line of the question specifically asks about Unity.

Comment: I did a "unity" key search and it didn't show up. Dunno, he/she also asks about other tools. OP should clarify.